# How to create and run a bash file?

Tags: bash, terminal

How to create a bash file?

I found following bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.wav; do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
  afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 "$f" "${f/wav/caf}"
done
```

I have `Mac` and `Windows`.

But I don't know where I have to put this and how I can run this script?

Comment: This might be a stupid questions, but I want to make sure: Are you running a Windows or a Linux system?

Comment: Then you can forget about most answers below, because they assumed you have a Linux system.

Comment: Is there any other option for me ?

Comment: On Mac it should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two different OS setup, I will split my answer in two parts.

### First: Windows

Windows does not have a Bash interpreter, nor the `afconvert` program the code above is trying tu run. Your best bet will be to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to install a Unix console on your Windows. Also I don't know, where you could get `afconvert` from.

### OSX

OSX does have a console and the `afconvert` software (at least my OSX does). You can simply drop the file in a folder and give it a name ending in `.sh`. Then you should be able to run it.

Comment: So I need to put above string into text file with .sh extension and then ?

Answer (score 3):

Just save the text into a file called `my_bash_script` a file, make it executable and run it from the command line like this:

```
chmod u+x my_bash_script
./my_bash_script
```

Judging by the file it will need to be in a directory containing *.wav files.

Comment: No such file or directory. Is command line = Terminal for Mac ?

Comment: @Devang: Yeah Terminal is the program to use for running scripts on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Just paste the text into a plaint text file and then mark it as executable:

```
chmod +x yourScript
```

To run it:

```
./yourScript
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the script anywhere you have your .wav files. When fallow instructions given here:
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html#sect_02_01_03